# Ordering svg elements after drawing

Tags: html, svg, z-index

I'm using react to dynamically draw out boxes and information. The information is visible when the user hovers the mouse over a box. This functionality works.

My issue is when an element is rendered after another element, then that information box will be underneath the previous box. The information box should always be on top. This is the current solution.

```html
<svg>
    <g>
        <rect> <!-- Always visible -->
        <text> <!-- Visible on rect hover -->
    </g>
    <g>
        <rect> <!-- Always visible -->
        <text> <!-- Visible on rect hover -->
    </g>
    ...
</svg>
```

I know the issue can be solved by regrouping the components, but then I run into the issue with hovering over the boxes. Is there a way to solve this similar to the old-fashion z-index?

Comment: You can't use z-index in svg. However you can use javascript to append the element you want at the end of the svg element. Please take a look at this pen: [SVG z-index](https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YXoEQe?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I eventually found was to group them as boxes and infoboxes, and then in the "infoboxes" group add an invisible box that listened for hover events.

```html
<svg>
    <g>
        <g>
            <rect> <!-- Always visible -->
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect> <!-- Always visible -->
        </g>
        ...
    </g>
    <g>
        <g>
            <rect> <!-- Always invisible -->
            <text> <!-- Visible on rect hover -->
        </g>
        <g>
            <rect> <!-- Always invisible -->
            <text> <!-- Visible on rect hover -->
        </g>
        ...
    </g>
    ...
</svg>
```